# RegEx expression to handle multiple conditions of breaking sentences

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am trying to make a regex that is used in an exception.

Therefore it must return false for these sentences (the leading digits are included in the strings):

> `3.{17} this is italics and should break.{18}`
>
> `4. this is another sentence and should break.`
>
> `5. This is another sentence and should break.`

And it must return true for these:

> `There are 2 reasons for this 1. you are here and 2. you are communicating.`
>
> `Is it 2? they wanted to know.`
>
> `1 digit at the beginning but with 1. with a period should return true.`

In other words, if the beginning of the string is a number followed by a period, it should return false (even if `"\{\d+\}"` follows it optionally) and the character following the space does not matter. And it must return true if the number and period (or `!` or `?`) is embedded in the sentence followed by a lower case character, in other cases it must be false.

As a further note: this goes into a java properties file, and the value is then passed to a perl5 regex engine to return broken text.

I try to express it in one expression, but somehow I cannot get it right.
This is what have come up with until now:

```
^([^0-9\.]+[\.]|
[^\.!\?]*[\?!]+[\?!\.]+|
[0-9]+[^\?!\.]+[\?!\.]+|
[^0-9]*[0-9]+[^\?!\.]+[\?!\.]+)
(\{\d+\}[\u0020\u00A0]|
[\u0020\u00A0]*)[a-z]
```

I seem to arrived at an impasse and can't see what is I have wrong.

Thanks for any advice.

**Update:**
A simpler format with look-ahead: `^(?!\d+\.)[^.!?]*[.!?]+(\{\d+\}\s|\s*)\p{Ll}` based on the comments.

Comment: Do the sentences also have quotes around them, and always have a space after `.`?

Comment: @l'L'l - no quotes, and spaces yes after the `.` or `!` or `?` I fixed the samples

Comment: I don't understand the question. The sample strings can be matched by `^\D`.

Comment: @melpomene The strings include the leading digits.

Comment: Try `/^(?!\d+\.).*\d[,!?]\s*\p{Ll}/s`

Comment: ... yes? That's why my regex checks for leading digits.

Comment: @melpomene Sorry, I will add one more to the list of false, but the I do have `[^0-9]` already, which is effectively the same.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `\p{Ll}` is the same as my `[a-z]` at the end, I believe.

Comment: @ib11: However, if you add  `u` modifier, `\p{Ll}` will match all Unicode lowercase letters.

Comment: Revised regex: `^(?!\d+\.)`

Comment: @melpomene: No, it does not account for *And it must return true if the number and period (or ! or ?) is embedded in the sentence followed by a lower case character, in other cases it must be false.*

Comment: `if the beginning of the string is a number followed by a period, it should return false` = `^(?!\d\.)`, `it must return true if the number and period (or ! or ?) is embedded in the sentence followed by a lower case character` = `.*[\d.!?][a-z]`. These are your stated 2 requirements. Is this a black hole question of _yes, but I need this too_. Why don't you state what you need right at the beginning ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, but that part makes no sense to me, so I'm only looking at the example strings because those are unambiguous.

Comment: Sorry, @sln I thought I was clear enough with the examples. I don't think that this is an additional "I need this too", the examples show and I just clarify it after the samples to be clear. The `^(?!\d\.)` I think is the key that I was missing. So I am testing it further.

Comment: Yeah, `3.{17}` is _not_ matched by `^(?!\d+\.)` where do you get that it matches ? Only in an alternate universe.

Comment: That's correct @sln, it does not match it and I did not say that **it** matches, I said it still seems the whole expression returns true. But I tracked it down now, it was another line in the java properties file.

Comment: I do not understand: [`^(?!\d+\.)[^.!?]*[.!?]+(\{\d+\}\s|\s*)\p{Ll}`](https://regex101.com/r/aY1fgp/1) does not match `3.{17} this is italics and should break.{18}`

Comment: Please clarify what you are doing, better with some fiddle.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew for your help. The `^(?!\d+\.)[^.!?]*[.!?]+(\{\d+\}\s|\s*)\p{Ll}` was actually working fine, I had another line in the code that was the bug. Your answer resolved the issue. Can you please post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?!\d+\.)[^.!?]*[.!?]+(\{\d+\}\s|\s*)\p{Ll}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bn89P0/1).

The pattern matches:

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `(?!\d+\.)` - a [negative lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) that will fail the match if its pattern is matched at the start of the string: 1+ digits followed with a dot
- `[^.!?]*` - 0+ chars other than `.`, `!` and `?`
- `[.!?]+` - 1 or more `.`, `!` or `?` symbols
- `(\{\d+\}\s|\s*)` - either a `{` + 1 or more digits + `}` or 0+ whitespaces (if you are not interested in the value captured with this *capturing* group, you may turn it into a *non-capturing* one by adding `?:` after the first `(`).
- `\p{Ll}` - a lowercase letter (if a `u` modifier is used, it will also match all Unicode lowercase letters).